# Product of primitve characters

Tags: number-theory, characters

I am studying the book Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields by Washington, and I come across a result that is not proved in the book.

Let $\chi$ and $\psi$ be two Dirichlet characters with conductors $f_{\chi}$ and $f_{\psi}$ respectively. Let us take the homomorphism
\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma: (\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{lcm(f_{\chi},f_{\psi})\mathbb{Z}})^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*
\end{eqnarray}
defined as $\gamma(n)=\chi(n)\psi(n)$, for every $n\in (\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{lcm(f_{\chi},f_{\psi})\mathbb{Z}})^*$. We need to prove that $\chi\psi$ is a primitive character corresponding to $\gamma$.

Please help with the same. Thank you!

Comment: As I read it in the book, there is nothing to be proved as it is *defining* $\chi\psi$ to be the primitive character induced by $\chi(n)\psi(n)$ . By itself $\chi(n)\psi(n)$ could be non primitive, you have an example in the book just below the definition you mention.

Comment: Ok, so they define it as the above. I thought we can prove it. Thank you very much. Yes I saw the example. 

I saw a few posts that says we can actually show that the product of primitive characters with co-prime moduli, is actually primitive. So thought maybe we can prove this too. Thanks again! @EstebanCrespi